# How to use Impulse relation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, momentum

Consider the following question from Kleppner and Kolenkow (4.10-second edition)

> A freight car of mass *M* contains a mass of sand *m*. At *t=0* a constant
> horizontal force F is applied in the direction of rolling and at the
> same time a port in the bottom is opened to let the sand flow out at
> constant rate *dm/dt*. Find the speed of the fright car when all the
> sand is gone. Assume the freight car is at rest at *t=0*.

If we write down the second law for the problem we get

$$F=m(t)\frac{dv}{dt}\\ 
\frac{F\,dt}{m(t)}=dv\\$$

Let $dm/dt=\gamma$, thus $m(t)= M + m - \gamma t$

$$\int\frac{F\,dt}{m(t)}=\int dv\\
F\int\frac{dt}{M + m - \gamma t}=\Delta v$$
$$\frac{F}{\gamma}\ln\frac{M+m}{M}=v$$

But using impulse relation we get
$$\int F\, dt =\Delta P\\
Ft=Mv$$
$$v=\frac{Ft}{M}$$

Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Newton's 2nd Law is given by $\vec{F} = d\vec{p}/dt$, not $\vec{F} = md\vec{v}/dt$ (unless $m$ is time-independent).

Comment: @march Sure, but I like to picture the following: to change the momentum of a system you can either apply a force to it or add/remove mass to/from it at some velocity. Thus, $M\,dv=F\,dt \pm U\,dm$. Here the second term is zero since there is no addition/removal of horizontal momentum. If you don't like this approach then you can also work out the difference of final and initial momentum explicitly and then divide by time to get force.  Both methods are equivalent.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist What do you mean by "add/remove mass... at some velocity".. velocity is rate of change of the displacement vector. The general second law is force equals rate of change of momentum, not mass (whether time dependent or not) times acceleration

Comment: Since the force is acting on both the freight car and the sand that is *in* the freight car, the $\Delta P$ on the right-hand side in the second derivation must also include the change in momentum of that amount of sand.  Let me see if I can work that out and see if it makes the two expressions equal.

Comment: Actually, I can't think of any way of computing the change in momentum of the sand without just going through the first calculation that you did.  The problem is that the force that acts *just* on the sand is exerted by the train car, and that force is necessarily *less* than $F$ since the freight car has mass.  Perhaps a more careful calculation involving a careful consideration of the *internal* forces acting might help.

Comment: @march is right, in the first derivation you're considering the change of momentum of the combined freight and sand system, that's why just releasing the sand from the car doesn't affect the overall momentum (similiar to a gun+bullet momentum that's conserved) and that's why $vdm/dt$ doesn't enter there as a contribution to the *total* $\dot{p}$. But then indeed in the second method, you also have to consider the continuum of momenta each small sand mass $\Delta m$ obtained when it was released at a certain $v(t)$ from the car, not only the change of momentum of the car as you do now